# Differentiate browser/tab close and refresh event?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angular

Differentiate browser/tab close and refresh event? I know this is not new question in stack overflow but still struggling out. Actually I need to logout user using server call if browser gets close.

I have tried  tab count logic. But when I have only one tab left then its impossible to tell if its refresh or tab/browser  close event .

Comment: You mean how to close and refresh browser event with a code c# javascript or jquery or something?

Comment: how about sendBeacon https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: I want to call api on only when browser  or all tabs gets close.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is for the user to stay signed in for only the session, you can use session cookies to store the auth information. A session cookie is cleared  when the website or browser is closed. See more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).

Comment: Actually I need to make server call in order to perform operation .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by you need to make a server call?

Comment: I meant by  api call.